# Как правильно разделить данные пробелом

Tags: angularjs

Например есть три поля:

- Фамилия
- Имя
- Отчество

Как правильно собрать вывод таким образом, чтобы эти данные лежали внутри одного элемента, разделенные пробелом, при условии что какое-то поле может быть не заполнено.

```
<input ng-model="user_name" md-input />
<input ng-model="user_last_name" md-input />
<input ng-model="user_father_name" md-input />

<span class="sub-heading" id="user_edit_position">{{user_name}} {{user_last_name}} {{user_father_name}}</span>
```

Если делать так, то пробелы будут оставаться даже если какое-нибудь поле не заполнено. Как правильно поступить?

Comment: Собери `$scope.user_name, `$scope.user_last_name` `$scope.user_father_name` в отдельную переменную в контроллере и выводи её в `<span>` через `ng-model`. Проверку на наличие можно делать через `ng-if`

Comment: Пример не покажите? не могу понять как передать данные ng-model в span...

Answer (score 1):

Простой способ: в начале и конце span.innerHTML поставить по пробелу и результат всегда будет выглядеть одинаково. Это будет работать потому что в HTML последовательности пробелов преобразуются в одиночныe пробелы (whitespace collapse)

```
<span class="sub-heading" id="user_edit_position"> {{user_name}} {{user_last_name}} {{user_father_name}} </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML проигнорирует любое количество пробелов.

`<span>Инван</span>` и `<span>  Инван</span>`

в большинстве случаев будут выглядеть одинаково. Так что ваш пример уже должен работать правильно.

Comment: в примере автора все три поля лежат в одном спане, а не каждый в своем

Comment: Логично. К чему вы это?

Comment: _Так что ваш пример уже должен работать правильно_ вы рассматриваете пример на спанах и делаете вывод, что пример в посте должен работать правильно, я лишь указал, что, так как в посте не спаны, то не должен